# Capturing meta data about how data was collected in a database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have information I'm going to put in a database, but there I need to store meta-data about where the data came from (whether the data was measured or calculated).
I have several attributes that might be both calculated and measured independently of each other.

The easy/naive way of solving this would be to have a boolean for each field, indicating whether the data was measured or not.
Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the number of possible states. Depends on whether and how you need to query for the data. Maybe a one-to-many table is better, maybe just a JSON or hstore object.

Comment: There are two possible states. I'll be querying the data regardless of whether it is measured or calculated, but I need to keep track in case data looks weird.

Comment: Also "states" as in "necessary columns".

Comment: You'd just add another column for each data item. In this case, naive and easy = good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's no need to complicate this one. A simple column to indicate the data source would be sufficient. If you'll only ever deal with "measured" vs "not measured" then boolean is fine.

Otherwise I'd make it a `smallint` that's a foreign key reference to a look-up table that initially just contains:

```
CREATE TABLE data_source (
    id smallint primary key,
    source_name text unique not null
);

INSERT INTO data_source(id, source_name) VALUES
(0, 'WhateverNotMeasuredIs'),
(1, 'Measured');
```

PostgreSQL also supports enumerations (enums), which are another good candidate for this. They're really only well suited to things that will never change, though, and are more of an optimisation. You can leave considering them for later.